# Find the difference of a starting line and a lineified curve of that line

Tags: linear-algebra

The easiest way to explain this is that I have a line. I know its length (please denote as L) and I turn it into a curved line with an consistent angle I know (denote as A, please), now comparing the the length, though it is exactly the same if you "lineify" it using the beginning point of the curve and the point it is farthest out and find the difference between the two "lines", all using variables. Please keep it simple, and explain thoroughly.

Comment: What is your question, and what do you mean by "lineify"?

Answer (score 0):

The only curve with a 'consistent angle' is a segment of a circle. So you're asking something about the short side of an isoceles triangle inside a circle with the apex at the centre. What's the difference between the length of the short side and the length of the corresponding segment? Since an isosceles triangle is two right-angle triangles, the short side length is $2hsin\theta$ where $h$ is the hypoteneuse and the radius of the circle. The length of the arc is $\theta/360\times2\pi h$ if $\theta$ is in degrees. Then just subtract for the difference between the two.